# How to update properly GCM registration id in application

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create an app that uses push notifications. I have done all the work in both 3rd-party server and application development and the notifications are sent successfully.

In this certain part of the application, the user will be registering to GCM and 3rd-party server, through a specific service, and then uploading to the 3rd-party server the football games that he wants to be notified when they are completed.

The problem that I'm facing is that when I uninstall the app, the GCM servers (when I'm sending a message) don't respond with the NotConnected error. So when I re-install the app the GCMRegistrar gives me a new registration id and this makes my server to have two different registration ids for the same user.

Although I can solve this problem with the help of the canonical id. In particular Google says

```
"canonical_ids": 1    
"results": [{ "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" }]
```

> success, but the registration ID should be updated in the server database (from 23 to 32)

So if I listen to google's advice, with changing the registration id to the older (working) one, this will cause afterwords the application, with the new registration id, to send the football games to the server with this specific new registration id and the server will not understand where to store this info.

I know that a registration id is not a user's id but a registered device's id.

My first thought is to let the server have different registration ids. So when I get a canonical id, I will ignore it. I don't like this idea though...

My second thought is when I change the registration id to the older one, to update it somehow into the app...

Can anybody tell me which sounds better to my situation? This is the first time that I use push notifications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So if I listen to google's advice, with changing the registration id to the older (working) one

That's the opposite of what Google tell you to do. They encourage you to remove the old ID from your DB and keep only the new registration ID.

Here's the [relevant quote](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical) :

> **Canonical IDs**
>
> On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well, everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined to be **the ID of the last registration requested by your application. This is the ID that the server should use** when sending messages to the device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the response. Make sure to **replace the registration ID stored in your server with this canonical ID**, as eventually the ID you're using will stop working.